# Configuring base package for component scan in Spring boot test

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-test

When I launch my *test* with the following annotations:

```
package com.hello.package.p1;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataMongoTest
@SpringBootTest
public class ClassATest {

@Autowired
Service1 serivce1; //fqn = com.hello.package.p1.Service1 

@Autowired
Service2 serivce2; //fqn = com.hello.package.p2.Service2 

...}

package com.hello.package.p1;

@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootConfiguration
public class MongoTestConfig {
...
}
```

***service1*** will be injected. But ***service2*** will not, since it is not in the same package as the test class. I get an error:

> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'service2'; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

How can I tell my testing context that I want to load/scan a certain package, for example `com.hello`?

Comment: Can you add your main `SpringBootApplication` too please? You can just add `ComponentScan` to the test and specify, but ideally you should just have the `SpringBootApplication` do it for you. Additionally you're mixing a slice test and a full boot test, you should pick one or the other in most situations.

Comment: @DarrenForsythe I've added @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.hello.package.p1", "com.hello.package.p2"}) and it worked !  THANKS !

Answer (score 24):

Good to add the test config above I have the following in test config and any test case. I am new to spring boot test but it work. Let me know, if I am wrong.

```
    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan("au.some.spring.package")
    public class TestConfig {
    }
```

```
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    @SpringBootTest(classes= TestConfig.class)
    @TestPropertySource({"classpath:application.yml", 
    "classpath:env-${testing.env}.properties"})
    public class DBDmoTest {

        @Autowired
        PartyRepository partyRepository;
        @Test
        public void test(){
            Assert.assertNull(partyRepository.findByEmailIgnoreCase("some@abc.com"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: you are loading application.yml via @TestPropertySource , doesn't sound right

Comment: Then what is your suggestion?

Comment: probably can be done with profile

Answer (score 21):

You can add a `TestConfig` class in your test package:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "com.hello.package.p1", "com.hello.package.p2" })
public class TestConfig {
}
```